# PageViewController and Orientation change

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, device-orientation, uipageviewcontroller

I have a bit of a strategy question regarding `UIPageViewControllers`. It seems like it would fit my requirements perfectly but there are a few things which I'm not sure about. I thought maybe someone out there may have a gem or two to share. :)

So here goes: I would like to use `PageViewCtl` to show content in either portrait or landscape mode, however, they have to be in the same controller (i.e. have the same view) regardless of what orientation the device is. The reason is that the content has to be zoomable in such a way (in landscape orientation) that both "pages" of content are zoomed at once, not separately. At this point, I can't really see how this could be handled in a `PageViewCtl` since, as far as I know, you can't share a view between 2 view controllers. So does anyone have any insight on this question? Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I stole this from Erica Sadun (https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook):

```
    // Update interface to the given page
- (void) fetchControllersForPage: (uint) requestedPage orientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation
{
    BOOL sideBySide = [self useSideBySide:orientation];
    int numberOfPagesNeeded = sideBySide ? 2 : 1;
    int currentCount = self.viewControllers.count;

    uint leftPage = requestedPage;
    if (sideBySide && (leftPage % 2)) leftPage--;

    // Only check against current page when count is appropriate
    if (currentCount && (currentCount == numberOfPagesNeeded))
    {
        if (pageNumber == requestedPage) return;
        if (pageNumber == leftPage) return;
    }

    // Decide the prevailing direction by checking the new page against the old
    UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection direction = (requestedPage > pageNumber) ? UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse;
    [self updatePageTo:requestedPage];

    // Update the controllers
    NSMutableArray *pageControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    SAFE_ADD(pageControllers, [self controllerAtPage:leftPage]);    
    if (sideBySide)
        SAFE_ADD(pageControllers, [self controllerAtPage:leftPage + 1]);

    [self setViewControllers:pageControllers direction: direction animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Entry point for external move request
- (void) moveToPage: (uint) requestedPage
{
    [self fetchControllersForPage:requestedPage orientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
}

#pragma mark Delegate

- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    NSUInteger indexOfCurrentViewController = 0;
    if (self.viewControllers.count)
        indexOfCurrentViewController = ((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view.tag;
    [self fetchControllersForPage:indexOfCurrentViewController orientation:orientation];

    BOOL sideBySide = [self useSideBySide:orientation];
    self.doubleSided = sideBySide;

    UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation spineLocation = sideBySide ? UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid : UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
    return spineLocation;
}
```

Give her some love.  And note the super-clever "if (sideBySide && (leftPage % 2)) leftPage--;", which ensures that the left page is always an odd-numbered page.

-A

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the info! What is SAFE_ADD by the way?

Comment: @user978838 Sorry I left that out-- the DEFINEs are:  `#define IS_IPHONE   ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define SAFE_ADD(_Array_, _Object_) {if (_Object_ && [_Array_ isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) [pageControllers addObject:_Object_];}
#define SAFE_PERFORM_WITH_ARG(THE_OBJECT, THE_SELECTOR, THE_ARG) (([THE_OBJECT respondsToSelector:THE_SELECTOR]) ? [THE_OBJECT performSelector:THE_SELECTOR withObject:THE_ARG] : nil)`